# Android Json/Gson issue

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having trouble with this json.

```
{"directory": {
         "employees": {"employee": [
             {
                 "field": [
                     {
                         "content": "Charlotte Abbott",
                         "id": "displayName"
                     },
                     {
                         "content": "Charlotte",
                         "id": "firstName"
                     },
```

I am casting it into a class that looks like this

```
@SerializedName("directory")
    public Directory directory;

    public class Directory
    {
        @SerializedName("employees")
        public Employees employees;
    }
    public class Employees
    {
        @SerializedName("employee")
        public List<Employee> employee;
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        @SerializedName("field")
        public List<Fields> fields;

        @SerializedName("id")
        public String employeeId;
    }
    public class Fields
    {
        @SerializedName("content")
        public String content;

        @SerializedName("id")
        public String label;
    }
```

And it is not reaching all the variables to insert the data when it serializes. Instead I am getting all nulls. I am however getting the right amount (number) of Directory objects so I know it is reaching that far. Anyone have some insight on what I am doing wrong here? The json is the way it is, I didn't design it, but it is how it is used.

Comment: Are you expecting only one `employees` in the directory?

Comment: no there could be as many as 10,000, or as few as 1

Comment: HOw are you getting right amount of directory objects?  The can be only one such object in this JSON config, same with employees.  I would think these should be arrays of objects, not just objects.  You should probably make sure the JSON structure fits your needs.

Comment: Shouldn't employees be an array instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a weird data structure you have to work with, but here is it.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = "{\"directory\": {\"employees\": {\"employee\": [{\"field\": [{\"content\": \"Charlotte Abbott\",\"id\": \"displayName\"},{\"content\": \"Charlotte\",\"id\": \"firstName\"}]}]}}}";

        Wrapper obj = (Wrapper) gson.fromJson(jsonString, Wrapper.class);

        System.out.println(obj.getDirectory().getEmployees().getEmployeeList()
                .get(0).getFieldList().get(0).getContent());
    }
}
```

You need a `Wrapper` class to wrap around `Directory`.

```
public class Wrapper {
    private Directory directory;

    public Directory getDirectory() {
        return directory;
    }

    public void setDirectory(Directory directory) {
        this.directory = directory;
    }
}
```

`Directory` class.

```
public class Directory {
    @SerializedName("employees")
    private Employees employees;

    public Employees getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(Employees employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

`Employees` class:

```
public class Employees {
    @SerializedName("employee")
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return employeeList;
    }

    public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }
}
```

`Employee` class:

```
public class Employee {
    @SerializedName("field")
    private List<Field> fieldList;

    public List<Field> getFieldList() {
        return fieldList;
    }

    public void setFieldList(List<Field> fieldList) {
        this.fieldList = fieldList;
    }
}
```

`Field` class:

```
public class Field {
    @SerializedName("content")
    private String content;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

See a JSON to Java Object using GSON example here: http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Comment: I did it a completely different way and its working just fine, but this is likely a better solution then mine :) I will give it a good look :) thanks.

Comment: @WIllJBD great :D you should share your solution, for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how it worked out, i had it right, i just wasn't validating the data correctly after it was being put in, and so I was losing it by not being able to assign it and store it for later access.

It is ugly but the map looks like this

```
DIRECTORY obj
{
    EMPLOYEES obj
    {
        List employee []
        {
            int id
            List fields[]
            {
                content
                id
            {     
        {    
    { 
{
```